# RSA Signing with Engine: passing message and not its digest

Tags: openssl, rsa

I have just begun writing an openssl engine. I see that all one needs is to define function pointers to the various calls. For RSA engine, implementing Signing, one must use `RSA_METHOD` struct:

```
 typedef struct rsa_meth_st
 {    
        const char *name;    

        int (*rsa_pub_enc)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
          unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);

        int (*rsa_pub_dec)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
          unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);    

        int (*rsa_priv_enc)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
          unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);

        int (*rsa_priv_dec)(int flen, unsigned char *from,
          unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);    

        int (*rsa_mod_exp)(BIGNUM *r0, BIGNUM *I, RSA *rsa);    

        int (*bn_mod_exp)(BIGNUM *r, BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *p,
          const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx, BN_MONT_CTX *m_ctx);

        int (*init)(RSA *rsa);

        int (*finish)(RSA *rsa);    

        int flags;    

        char *app_data; /* ?? */    

        int (*rsa_sign)(int type, unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_len,
           unsigned char *sigret, unsigned int *siglen, RSA *rsa);//here m points to digest of type 'type'

        int (*rsa_verify)(int type, unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_len,
           unsigned char *sigbuf, unsigned int siglen, RSA *rsa);

 } RSA_METHOD;
```

However, I don't see any `SignInit`, `SignUpdate` pointers like in the `EVP_CIPHER` or `EVP_MD` structs.

I need to redirect the `SignInit`, `SignUpdate` to our library.
I need to forward the "original" message and **NOT its digest** to our implementation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "you can't." The OpenSSL library API is a defined, published interface. It's already in use by thousands of programs, none of which do what you ask, because the standard already told them how to write their code.

Comment: Ok I am not sure if I am missing something here. Aren't there RSA engines which do the signing for openssl? Am I to understand that these engines also receive only the the message digest to sign? Don't they directly get the original message which is then used to compute the digest internally in their implementation?

Comment: @user900785, the message digest function is in use elsewhere, for many purposes. Which invocation was done for the purpose of signing? Who knows! He could track data and signatures and try to match something up, but there would be no guarantee of universal reliability, as there would if it could be intercepted in the API as he's asking.

Comment: Thanks! However, somehow I am not convinced about one thing. I do see engines like pkcs-11 sureware, nCipher etc.They must also be able to use their smartcard engine to do the signing for them as the private key is stored on the device. How do you think they do this? I am unable to get my hands on any examples. Do they also just use the digest and 'sign' them?

Comment: His request was specific to the OpenSSL API, and that's what I answered. Other libraries combine the operations of digesting and signing behind a single call. This offers the advantage of simplicity (moving a complex process into a tested API is good) but lacks flexibility, such as might be needed when MD5 is broken.